# Accepting input from the click of a button

Tags: vb.net

Inside of an algorithm, I need to create a piece of code in an IF statement where the condition is the click of a button (object on a form).

Following the code that Visual Studio automatically generates when you double click on a button, I followed the example of:

```
btn_enter.click
```

However this brings up the error of

> 'Public Event Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

As a result of the error, could I be shown how to use the 'RaiseEvemt' statement so that I can use the click in an if statement like so:

```
If btn_enter.Click Then


        End If
```

Comment: Events cannot be called directly, you should whether write your condition in Click event, or set a variable in the click event and check that variable.

Comment: `I need to create a piece of code in an IF statement where the condition is the click of a button` sounds like the ultimate misuse of GUI objects as variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do lends itself more naturally to a checkbox or radiobutton.  Note that a checkbox also has an appearance property which makes it look like a button, but with checkbox-like behaviour ie it stays down when clicked.

You would then be able to write code along the lines of

```
If checkbox1.checked then
. . .
```